# How to display rupee symbol in my java class?

Tags: java

```
if(this.currency.equalsIgnoreCase("₹")) {
    r="₹ "+r;
}
```

I want to compare `₹`(Indian rupee symbol) in java. Here I am trying to print currency rupee symbol, but instead it is displaying the symbol like `â?¹`.

How to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 8):

You can try with:

```
if(this.currency.equals("\u20B9")) {
    r="₹ "+r;
}
```

`"\u20B9"` is the java encoding for rupee symbol.

More info:

- [Unicode Character 'INDIAN RUPEE SIGN'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm) .

Comment: I tried it but instead of rupee symbol I am getting "?" symbol

Comment: change the encoding of your program... as given in the link... also the charset you are having in your system doesn't supports rupee symbol....

Comment: even I am not getting the rupee symbol. As you said the charset  in my sytem is not supporting rupee symbol. Is there any solution to overcome it in a simple way?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be not much about the compare part of that snippet but mainly related to the printing, to display that characters correctly wrap `System.out` in an `OutputPrintWriter` with an UTF-8 encoding, it's needed on some OS configuration:

```
OutputStreamWriter stdOut=new OutputStreamWriter(System.out,"UTF8");
stdOut.println("₹");
```

Comment: Yes, actually my problem is I want to use rupee symbol in my java class, but Instead of that it is showing some other symbol?

Comment: My guess is that you are seeing this problem because you os has a default charset (some english charset?) that does not support the rupee symbol, my answer should fix it. Anyway, the compare part should/must work, so you don't have to worry about that. `"₹".equals("₹")` gives `true`, right?

Comment: Does those two lines work? Is the rupee symbol displayed correctly?

Comment: The fix on the OS side depends on the OS you are using and if installing the missing charset (it means a different thing in each OS) is not enough it could be hard to fix it...

Comment: hey I am sorry which two lines you are asking about? I thought it about my code snippet and replied as yes.

Comment: My answer above, where i create a new output stream with UTF8 encoding :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    String string = "\u20B9";
    byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

    string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String s="₹";

if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("₹")) {
  System.out.println("if condition"+s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Enable "UTF-8" in your editor (eclipse/netbean)
- Or use unicode ("\u20B9").

Answer (score -1):

```java
String string = "\u20B9";
byte[] utf8 = string.getBytes("UTF-8");

string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)